# Best practices for user permissions in Postgresql?

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql

I'm new to postgres, and I'm trying to figure out how to best secure my databases when running web applications.

In MySQL, I tend to use an administration user for things like creating databases, creating tables, modifying schemas, dropping tables etc.: for all activities that should never happen when the database is used by some application on an ongoing basis. Then I have a second user (one for each application) that has (only) the rights the application needs, like insert, update etc. This avoids that application bugs / hacks have catastrophic consequences.

Now I'm trying to figure out how to do a similar thing in postgres. It seems that postgres databases have an "owner", unlike MySQL ones. If I used my scheme above, should the administration user "own" all databases for all applications? Or what are some best practices here?

Addition: I'm just finding out that granting permissions on "all tables" seems to mean "all tables currently defined" and does not include future tables. Unlike MySQL, where "on foo.*" means all current and future tables. Is that correct? Is there a way to include future tables as well in the grant statement, or do I have re-execute every time?

Comment: A MySQL database is equivalent to a Postgres schema

Answer (score 9):

My best practises are:

1. Create custom database for app
2. Create custom schema for custom DB for app
3. Create DDL role
4. Create DML role
5. Revoke ALL on created custom DB from PUBLIC
6. Revoke create on schema PUBLIC into DB-ses postgres and created custom DB
7. Grant USAGE and CREATE on custom schema for DDL role
8. Grant only USAGE on custom schema for DML role
9. Create user with DDL role for DDL app operations(for flyway or liquibase migrations, creating/alter/drop entities etc.)
10. Create user with DML role for DML app operations(SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE)
11. !Under DDL user! Alter default privileges in custom schema to DML role

It looks like:

My scripts:

01-init.sql

```
CREATE DATABASE mysuperdb;

REVOKE ALL ON DATABASE mysuperdb FROM PUBLIC;

REVOKE CREATE ON SCHEMA public FROM PUBLIC;

CREATE ROLE ddl_custom_role WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'PWDPWD';

GRANT
    CONNECT
    ON DATABASE mysuperdb TO ddl_custom_role;

GRANT
    TEMPORARY
    ON DATABASE mysuperdb TO ddl_custom_role;

CREATE ROLE dml_custom_role WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'PWDPWD';

GRANT
    CONNECT
    ON DATABASE mysuperdb TO dml_custom_role;

GRANT
    TEMPORARY
    ON DATABASE mysuperdb TO dml_custom_role;
```

02-init.sql

```
REVOKE CREATE ON SCHEMA public FROM PUBLIC;
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS mysuperschema;
CREATE USER flywayuser WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'PWDPWD';
CREATE USER appuser WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'PWDPWD';
GRANT
    USAGE,
    CREATE
    ON SCHEMA mysuperschema TO ddl_custom_role;
GRANT
    USAGE
    ON SCHEMA mysuperschema TO dml_custom_role;
GRANT
    ALL
    ON ALL SEQUENCES mysuperschema TO ddl_custom_role;
GRANT
    USAGE,
    SELECT
    ON ALL SEQUENCES mysuperschema TO dml_custom_role;
GRANT ddl_custom_role TO flywayuser;
GRANT dml_custom_role TO appuser;
```

03-init.sql

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA mysuperschema
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON TABLES TO dml_custom_role;
```

Run order(Pay attention under which user to run script!):

1. Under user postgres on DB postgres:

   psql -U postgres -d postgres -a -f 01-init.sql
2. Under user postgres on DB MYSUPERDB:

   psql -U postgres -d mysuperdb -a -f 02-init.sql
3. Under user FLYWAYUSER on DB MYSUPERDB :

   psql -U flywayuser -d mysuperdb -a -f 03-init.sql

As result, you have one user for migrations(**flywayuser**), which can CREATE, ALTER, DROP tables
and another user(**appuser**) which has **only access** for SELECT, INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE into tables which created flywayuser

Comment: In your example above, any resource created by `flywayuser` will be inaccessible to `appuser`.

Comment: @SergeyAkopov What do you mean "any resource created by flywayuser will be inaccessible to appuser"?
I just checked, and all works fine)
You can check it into my [docker-compose](https://disk.yandex.ru/d/ABbg-R1fT2WHMA)

After run, you can create table by flywayuser and use DML with that table by appuser

Comment: Thanks for sharing! I recommend avoiding setting a password to `dml_custom_role` and `ddl_custom_role` as this in fact creates users.

Comment: @DanielZohar it's just example)
Of course the password won’t be in the file)

Comment: What @DanielZohar meant is that by not assigning a password you will keep the `dml_custom_role` purely to a role (to distinguish it from a user).

Comment: @maulik13 It is planned that it will be a technical user and therefore it should have a password

Comment: @DenisDavydov Sure that can be fine. My main comment then is that it is a bit confusing to have a different naming convention between `dml_custom_role` and `flywayuser`. You call one role and the other user but set passwords on both.

Answer (score 4):

One adminstrative user is OS user postgres, who has access as per pg_hba.conf. This is a/the system account. Never mess with it.

Of course a dba must have his own login, create it with option `superuser`.

For your web app you create a web app login, and a database with the web app as database owner.

This is usually necessary because most web applications would want to create and change their tables, instead of delegating this work to the admin like it is customary in data center setups.

This way you have a separation of access between different databases.

BTW the postgresql docs are very good, just read up on it, for example [about PG database roles](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/user-manag.html), [the database owner](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/manage-ag-createdb.html), and [client authentication](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/client-authentication.html) which is a PG speciality.

Answer (score 1):

It is best to keep things simple. If your two-tier setup works for you, I would recommend keeping it rather than introducing additional administrative overhead in creating an additional role for database ownership. If you need to add more varying levels of privilege, you might then reconsider.